# Is there any way to iterate for loop multiplicatively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Basically, all I want to know is that whether such thing is possible with for loop or not.

I used while loop so as to increment value 2 times the previous one.

```
increment = 1
while (increment <= 10):
    print (increment)
    increment *= 2
```

Comment: No, it isn't.  The appropriate implementation is just as you have done it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. That solves my problem.

Comment: You could write a generator that's similar to `range()` but multiplies instead of adding.